# jQuery Maskedinput plugin: Completed event after pasting not work

Tags: events, jquery-plugins, maskedinput, pasting

I have trouble with using jQuery [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)
text typing successfully works, but if I **paste** text into masked textbox - I cannot catching **Completed** event.

Example from plugin site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function ($) {
         $("#testtext").mask("99/99/9999", { completed: function () {
             alert("You typed the following: " + this.val());
         } });
     });
</script>
```

Anyone done similar?

Answer (score 4):

I ended up:

1. binding to the **paste** event and
2. then getting the pasted **val()**-ue after a brief **setTimeout**
   (since pasted data doesn't make it into the control when event is triggered) and
3. finally invoking the same method as **complete**

---

```
// mask fields
$('#Ssn').mask("999-99-9999",
    { completed: function () { lookupPersonAsync(this.val()); } }
);
// fix paste bug
$('#Ssn').bind('paste', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var ssn = $('#Ssn').val();
        if (ssn.length == 11) lookupPersonAsync(ssn);
    }, 100);
});
```

---

There might be a simpler solution, but this seemed simplest since it turns out it's not that easy to get to clipboard data in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to trigger the Completed event upon pasting. It might not be the pretties solution, or fool-proof by any means, but for my purposes, it will suffice.

Also with the limited testing that I did with 2 seperate masks, I didn't encounter any problems. The masks I used were `aa99aaa999` and `(999) 999-9999`.

I simply updated the bind event of the paste handler. All this logic does is ensures that the position of the cursor is >= the length of the mask, and if that is the case, it will trigger the completed function, assuming you have passed it.

```
.bind(pasteEventName, function() {
                        setTimeout(function() { 
                            input.caret(checkVal(true)); 
                            if(checkVal(true) >= len && settings.completed){
                                settings.completed.call(input);
                            }
                        }, 0);
```

Hope this helps someone out.